# Converting expression to quadratic formula

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I want to manipulate and represent the following expression in a more presentable way.

```
-((6 (-beta + 2 beta x/n))/(8 beta + 9 n)) + 
 3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(
  2 beta^2 + 9 beta n x/n - 9 beta n (x/n)^2)/(8 beta + 9 n)^2]
```

This looks like a quadratic formula (Not necessarily in the variable `x`). How can I manipulate the expression above to get the coefficients `a,b,c` to represent it as

$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4 a c}}{2 a}$$

My formula looks like a qudratic with `a=(8 beta + 9 n)`

Comment: `Series[expr, {x, 0, 4}] // Normal` shows that you expression is not quadratic in `x`

Comment: Please see the edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start by defining

```
f = -((6 (-β + 2 β x/n))/(8 β + 9 n)) + 3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 β^2 + 9 β n x/n - 9 β n (x/n)^2)/(8 β + 9 n)^2];
```

and then checking if we can find a formula $f^2+u f+v=0$:

```
f^2 + u f // Expand
(*    lots of terms    *)
```

notice that the three last terms in this expansion have a square root in them. Together, they are exactly zero if $u$ has the value

```
Solve[%[[-3 ;;]] == 0, u] // FullSimplify
(*    {{u -> -((12 (n - 2 x) β)/(n (9 n + 8 β)))}}
```

Let's try it out: this combination is indeed square-root-free,

```
f^2 - (12 (n - 2 x) β)/(n (9 n + 8 β)) * f // FullSimplify
(*    (18 (n - x) x β)/(n^2 (9 n + 8 β))    *)
```

and therefore

```
f^2 - (12 (n - 2 x) β)/(n (9 n + 8 β)) * f - (18 (n - x) x β)/(n^2 (9 n + 8 β)) // FullSimplify
(*    0    *)
```

Expand this equation by multiplying all terms by $n^2 (8 \beta +9 n)$:

```
n^2 (9 n + 8 β) * f^2 - 12 n (n - 2 x) β * f - 18 (n - x) x β // FullSimplify
(*    0    *)
```

Now we have a quadratic equation for $f$, and the formula you're looking for follows from it with

$$
a = n^2 (9n+8\beta)\\
b=-12\beta n(n-2x)\\
c=-18\beta x(n-x)
$$

```
a = n^2 (9 n + 8 β);
b = -12 n (n - 2 x) β;
c = -18 (n - x) x β;

Assuming[n > 0 && β > 0,
  f == (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a) // FullSimplify]
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```
-((6 (-beta + 2 beta x/n))/(8 beta + 9 n)) + 
   3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 beta^2 + 9 beta n x/n - 
        9 beta n (x/n)^2)/(8 beta + 9 n)^2] // 
  PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{6 \text{beta} (n-2 x)+3 \sqrt{2} n \sqrt{\text{beta} \left(2 \text{beta}+\frac{9 x (n-x)}{n}\right)}}{n (8 \text{beta}+9 n)}$$

If you want it with `±`:

```
-((6 (-beta + 2 beta x/n))/(8 beta + 9 n)) + 
  3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(2 beta^2 + 9 beta n x/n - 
       9 beta n (x/n)^2)/(8 beta + 9 n)^2] // FullSimplify;
PlusMinus @@ % // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{6 \text{beta} (n-2 x)}{n (8 \text{beta}+9 n)}\pm \frac{3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\text{beta}} \sqrt{2 \text{beta} n+9 x (n-x)}}{\sqrt{n} (8 \text{beta}+9 n)}$$